# MainWindow minimizes when ChildWindow open MessageBox and closes

Tags: c#, wpf

The program have a MainWindow with buttons to open Child Windows. When one of this child shows a messagebox, when I close the child, the main window minimizes.

```
protected void EventBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Child child = new child();
    child.Show();
    child.Owner = this;
}
```

SOLUTION:

Thanks to @Oscar Martinez

Child:

```
public partial class Child: Window
{
    public Child()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello world!");
    }

    // this is what you need to add
    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Owner = null;
    }
}
```

Parent:

```
public partial class Parent: Window
{
    public Parent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Child child = new Child();
        child.Show();
        child.Owner = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i tried this never happen for me but is better you focused on your main window after closing child window

Comment: @Lithium the question is how can I avoid it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same behavior. It was easily solved by handling the `Closing` event of the `Child` form.

Child:

```
public partial class Child: Window
{
    public Child()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello world!");
    }

// this is what you need to add
    private void Child_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)     
    {
        this.Owner = null;
    }
}
```

Parent:

```
 public partial class Parent: Window
    {
        public Parent()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Child child = new Child();
        child.Show();
        child.Owner = this;
    }
}
```

If you minimize the Parent, the Child also minimizes.

And If you close the Child, the Parent does not minimize.

Comment: I can't do that because the child window must be owned by the Main Window. If I change that when i minimize the Main Window the child window don't minimize and it shows another window in the taskbar as well.

Comment: If you minimize Main Window, the Child form too. Test it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read the code correctly. I though the child.Owner = null; sentence were in MainWindow. It works perfectly thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it too but like Shahrooz it never happen.

Try this, maybe it may help you :

```
protected void EventBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (Child child = new Child())
    {
         child.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with ShowDialog is that it freeze the Main Window when I open a Child Window, freezing the minimize and close button in the Main Window as well, and I need those buttons working

Comment: I can't reproduce your bug.

Comment: When you opened a window with ShowDialog, the main window can't be used. The hole point of putting child.Owner = this; is because i want that when I minimize main window the child minimizes as well. If i can't use main windows i can't do that at all.

Answer (score 0):

Parent window is not minimized, it's just getting back of other applications. To avoid it, set parent window's topmost property.

```
public ParentWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Topmost = true;
    }
```

then, create child windows as follows.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Child child = new Child();
    child.Owner = this;
    child.Show();        
}
```

Comment: This works too but I prefer the other option because I don't want Main Window to be always on top of all the aplications. If I click in other app in the taskbar my application need to get back that application and with that configuration the only posibility to minimize Main Window is by clicking the button.